# How to serialize type information using custom serializer also for sub documents using NEST and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, serialization, json.net, nest

I'm using the example on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_serializing_type_information to get $type information for the documents in elasticsearch.

However as mentioned on the page this only returns type information for the outer document:

> the type information is serialized for the outer MyDocument instance, but not for each MySubDocument instance in the SubDocuments collection.

So my question now is if anyone knows how to also get type information for sub documents?

I've tried using the same JsonSerializerSettings as in their example separate from Elasticsearch (using LinqPad) and there I get type information also for sub documents:

```
void Main()
{
    var temp = new ListBlock
    {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Titel",
        Blocks = new List<BlockContent> {
            new InnerBlock {
                Id = 11,
                MyProperty ="Inner Property"
            },
            new InnerBlock2 {
                Id = 12,
                MyProperty2 = "Inner property 2"
            }
        }
    };

    var serializeOptions = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All,
        NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };
    var serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp, serializeOptions);
    serialized.Dump();
}

public class BlockContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ListBlock : BlockContent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<BlockContent> Blocks { get; set; }
}

public class ListBlock2 : BlockContent
{
    public string Title2 { get; set; }
    public List<BlockContent> Blocks { get; set; }
}

public class InnerBlock : BlockContent
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class InnerBlock2 : BlockContent
{
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

This code results in the following json:

```
{
  "$type": "UserQuery+ListBlock, LINQPadQuery",
  "Title": "Titel",
  "Blocks": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+BlockContent, LINQPadQuery]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "UserQuery+InnerBlock, LINQPadQuery",
        "MyProperty": "Inner Property",
        "Id": 11
      },
      {
        "$type": "UserQuery+InnerBlock2, LINQPadQuery",
        "MyProperty2": "Inner property 2",
        "Id": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  "Id": 1
}
```

Using these versions at the moment:

- Elasticsearch 7.4.2
- Nest 7.4.2

**Update:**

The solution provided by Russ Cam below works like a charm for the data model included in the response, however I've put together an example below based on how we create indices (using automap) and bulk index the initial list of documents. This works fine if we exclude the list of Guids (CategoryIds) in the model but if we include it the following exception is thrown:

```json
{
    "took": 8,
    "errors": true,
    "items": [{
            "index": {
                "_index": "testindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "status": 400,
                "error": {
                    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to parse field [categoryIds] of type [keyword] in document with id '1'. Preview of field's value: '{$values=[], $type=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Guid, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib}'",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                        "reason": "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:140"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "index": {
                "_index": "testindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "status": 400,
                "error": {
                    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to parse field [categoryIds] of type [keyword] in document with id '2'. Preview of field's value: '{$values=[], $type=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Guid, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib}'",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                        "reason": "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:141"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a simple (.Net 5) console application where this behaviour hopefully can be reproduced by others also:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Nest;
using Nest.JsonNetSerializer;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ElasticsearchTypeSerializer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string IndexName = "testindex";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool,
                (builtin, settings) => new MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings));
            settings.DisableDirectStreaming();
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            CreateIndex(client);
            IndexDocuments(client);
            var documents = GetDocuments(client);
        }

        private static void CreateIndex(IElasticClient client)
        {
            var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create(IndexName, x => x.Map<MyDocument>(m => m.AutoMap()));
        }

        private static void IndexDocuments(IElasticClient client)
        {
            var documents = new List<MyDocument>
            {
                new()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "My first document",
                    OwnerId = 2,
                    SubDocuments = new List<SubDocument>
                    {
                        new MySubDocument {Id = 11, Name = "my first sub document"},
                        new MySubDocument2 {Id = 12, Description = "my second sub document"}
                    }
                },
                new()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "My second document",
                    OwnerId = 3,
                    SubDocuments = new List<SubDocument>
                    {
                        new MySubDocument {Id = 21, Name = "My third sub document"}
                    }
                }
            };

            var bulkIndexResponse = client.Bulk(b => b.Index(IndexName).IndexMany(documents).Refresh(Refresh.True));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<MyDocument> GetDocuments(IElasticClient client)
        {
            var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s.Index(IndexName).Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
            var documents = searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
            return documents;
        }
    }


    public class MyDocument
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public List<Guid> CategoryIds { get; set; } = new();
        public List<SubDocument> SubDocuments { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubDocument
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySubDocument : SubDocument
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySubDocument2 : SubDocument
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    public class MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer : ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase
    {
        public MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer(IElasticsearchSerializer builtinSerializer,
            IConnectionSettingsValues connectionSettings)
            : base(builtinSerializer, connectionSettings)
        {
        }

        protected override JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            return new()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this issue is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want type information to be included for typed collections on a document, the derived contract resolver can be omitted, which supresses the type handling for collection item types

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, 
        (builtin, settings) => new MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings));
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var document = new MyDocument
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "My first document",
        OwnerId = 2,
        SubDocuments = new[]
        {
        new MySubDocument { Name = "my first sub document" },
        new MySubDocument { Name = "my second sub document" },
    }
    };

    var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(document);

}

public class MyDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MySubDocument> SubDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class MySubDocument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer : ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase
{
    public MySecondCustomJsonNetSerializer(IElasticsearchSerializer builtinSerializer, IConnectionSettingsValues connectionSettings)
        : base(builtinSerializer, connectionSettings) { }

    protected override JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings() =>
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Russ! This works like a charm with the provided data model but I've updated my original question with an example where this doesn't work, including a list of Guids to the MyDocument class. Any idea why the code works without the list of Guids but crashes if included?

Comment: The mapping in the index needs to match the _shape_ of the JSON structure that's now being sent. In the case of a `List<Guid>`, it sounds like this is mapped as a `keyword` datatype in the mapping, based on the response message. Now however, with the addition of type information, a `List<Guid>` will be serialized to an array of JSON objects because type information is included. This is a problem because the mapping expects a JSON string or array of strings to be sent. The index mapping will need to be changed to match the new JSON structure, which requires a new index and explicit mapping

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense and also makes the error message understandable :-) However, do you know how a explicit mapping such as this can be applied to for instance CategoryId? I will try to find a working solution but thought I'd have to ask if you know it from the top of your head. Or if possible, is there a way to only add type-information to fields that are based on our own classes and disregard for instance List<Guid>?

Comment: This post on Github (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1155) pointed me to a direction of adding [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)] to CategoryIds which seems to work, now it is being indexed as a simple list of Guids insted and the subdocuments have type information attached to them.

Comment: @MartinEmanuelsson that's one way to apply `TypeNameHandling`, with attributes. If you wanted a more general approach, this can be done in the contract resolver's `CreateContract` method that is in the link in the question. For example, you might apply `TypeNameHandling.All` only for types from your assembly, and `TypeNameHandling.None` for everything else.

Comment: That sounds like an even nicer solution but can't really get it to work. I've removed the override of CreateJsonSerializerSettings and have this code in CreateContract, do you see anything obviously wrong in this code?

Comment: `protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
{
  var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

  if (contract is not JsonContainerContract containerContract) return contract;

  if (contract.CreatedType.Namespace != null && !contract.CreatedType.Namespace.StartsWith("System"))
  {
    containerContract.ItemTypeNameHandling ??= TypeNameHandling.All;
  }
  else
  {
    containerContract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
  }

  return contract;
}`

Comment: My apologies, it can be set by overriding `CreateProperty`, calling `base.CreateProperty()`, and inspecting the returned `PropertyType`

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid.Every time `CreateProperty` is being called it's for a property from the `System` namespace for some reason. Therefore I've also included overriding `CreateArrayContract` setting `ItemTypeNameHandling` in a similar manner but it still tries to include type information for my List of Guids when indexing my documents. I understand that it's a lot to ask but if you have the possibility to look at an example application where this works, starting from my console app for instance, I'd very much appreciate it. Feels like it's so close to working 100%.

Comment: Still struggling a bit with this one, I can get it to not add type information to the list of Guids but add it to the list of SubDocument but then there is no type information on the base document, MyDocument in the example app. Or I can have type information on the base document but then type information is also added to the list of Guids :-( Trying to use `CreateProperty`, ´CreateObjectContract´, ´CreateContract´ and any combination of available overrides but can't find a perfect match.